# Best practice for pre-warming cache by calling the API ahead of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, api-design

Asked by thomhlee, 0 votes

We have a service that is expected to not be able to meet latency requirement mainly due to downstream dependency latency.

We want some kind of a pre-fetch mechanism. What we decided we want to add cachcing (Doesn't have to be in-memory DB) ability, which can be manually warmed up ahead of time so when later fetched, it can be fetched quickly from cache instead of calling downstream services.

Which approach is better? We also have potential use cases to react to SNS events to pre-warm the cache ahead of time.

Approach #1: Use the same Fetch API to pre-warm cache.

Pros:

```
We only need to implement 1 API
```

Cons:

```
We cannot distinguish requests from pre-warming caching from requests that wants to fetch data.
One could throttle the other, this is a high TPS service
```

Approach #2: Have a separate API to request a pre-fetch, but use the normal fetch API later to get the data.

Pros:

```
One API will not affect the other API
Separation of concerns
```

Cons:

```
More development work / possible more infrastructure
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am implementing a similar solution (same use-case) wherein I pre-fetch data into the cache (/login event from API Gateway), which would later be used for rendering the user's landing page (the dashboard + available actions (UI action authorization)). After which it works out as a side-cache pattern.